# How to get an image src in another page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages; `main.html` and `result.html`.

main.html:

```html
    <img id="preview" src="" alt="">
    <button id="done" type="button">done</button>
```

result.html:

```html
    <img id="search" src="" alt="">
```

In `main` page, I upload an image and the preview is shown in `preview` of `main`. And then I cropped this image using cropper js module.

crop.js:

```
const done = document.getElementById('done');
const imgcropped = document.getElementById('img-cropped');

done.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    imgcropped.src = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
})
```

I want to get `imgcropped.src` to the `search.src` in `result`. How can I get the `main` image to the `result`?

Comment: you need a relation between main.html and result.html, then you use a message system

Comment: Tho you want to open two pages at the same time or the user will navigate from main to result? In the first approach, you need really create a relation between two pages and use a message system (post message). In the second approach, you will need to forward the data to the second page as a request parameter (querystring or post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `localStorage`.

In main.html:

```
const done = document.getElementById('done');
const imgcropped = document.getElementById('img-cropped');

done.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var newSrc = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
    imgcropped.src = newSrc;
    window.localStorage.setItem("imgcropped", newSrc);
});
```

And in result.html:

```
var searchImg = document.getElementById("search")
if(window.localStorage.getItem("imgcropped") !== null){
    searchImg.src = window.localStorage.getItem("imgcropped");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you save me! XD